# How secure is firebase with auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am not sure where to begin but I recently saw 'Firebase' while searching for no server database, while it seems interesting to me, I was little worried about putting my api codes directly in the js files, which obviously can be seen through source but I have read that you can change the read/write rules and need authentication. so I no longer worried about API after reading through some pages

but the main question is:

I wanted to create an admin portal for my page, so example my admin page is located in **localhost/admin/** <<< The page will simply have a login form which is to access the portal, so everything is set

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

      if (user) {
      window.location = '/portal.html'
      }

      else {
      // Do nothing
      }
});

$("#loginbtn").click(function() {

var email = $('#login-name').val();
var password = $('#login-pass').val();

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.

});

});
```

So when I log in successfully it will redirect me to that page but can someone just look through source code and then go that page manually and enter it?

Or even if I intend to build one page application and decide to change the page state after login, whatever functions i'm going to do after that, can someone still find out and inject the code ?

I'm not really expert on this but this what I was thinking before starting my project, so is there is any other way around?

Comment: You may want to think about routing through libaraies as well as firesafe https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/02/firesafe-add-complex-security-logic-to.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add admin capabilities and you are using Firebase real-time database, you need to set some custom Firebase rules to only allow admins to access restricted data. So if a non-admin user signs in, they are unable to modify/access admin only data.
One way to do this with Firebase rules is to have a `/whitelist` node with `uid1: "bojeil@bla.com", uid2: "puf@bla.com"` for storing all whitelisted admin UIDs and then a top-level security rule for restricted admin only nodes like `".write": "auth != null && root.child('whitelist').child(auth.uid).exists()"`. It's fairly simple, but goes a long way.

If you are not using real-time database and building a traditional web application, you need to protect restricted admin only resources. You will need to send the Firebase ID token to your backend. You can do that by setting a session cookie with its value and making sure to update that session cookie every hour or so when the Firebase ID token is refreshed. When the cookie is sent with your request, you check for it, decode it (you can use the Firebase Admin SDKs for that) and check that the user it belongs to is an admin. If so, you can allow access, otherwise you block access. On every page, you would add an onAuthStateChanged listener. If that triggers with null, you redirect to the sign-in page. If the session cookie contains an ID token for a non-admin, you can do a HTTP redirect on your server to the user non-admin section.

tldr; you need to enforce the check on your backend by sending the Firebase ID token with the request and double checking its user has adequate privileges.

Comment: For point 1 I nowadays often have a `/whitelist` node with `uid1: "bojeil@bla.com"`, `uid2: "puf@bla.com"` and then a top-level security rule like `".write": "auth != null && root.child("whitelist').child(auth.uid).exists()"`. It's fairly simple, but goes a long way. @bojeil: feel free to add this sample to your answer. :-)

Comment: Done. Thanks Frank.

Comment: Could you change ("whitelist') with ('whitelist')